# How to change class intervals in R?

Tags: r, group-by, intervals

I have age group categories of 15-24, 25-34, 35-44, 45-54, 55-64, 65-74, 75 and older.  But I want to only have 3 groups groups: Ages 15-49, Ages 50 and older, and both Age Groups.  I have the raw data for each age group.

How do I code for this new class interval in R?

Comment: Hi you can use cut() .

Comment: Unless you have the raw data per age, what you are asking is technically impossible. You would need to split the 45-54 group and 15-24 group. You could do 15-54 with cut()

Comment: Hello,  Yes I have the raw data per age group.  Sorry I did not clarify that!